# Eclipse CDT: Symbol could not be resolved

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

These symbols are #defined in a C header file, nothing different about them apparently, all defined the same way.

Some work, some don't.  Therefore, on some files I get a whole bunch of red 'error' lines in the right hand side margin, obscuring any 'real' errors.

Code compiles fine; I know there are actually no errors.  Performed all the 'index' tasks on the project as per similar hits on the web.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case was the end of the previous line of the offending #define, in the .h file (found using hex editor).  If the line ended in 0x0D, the following #define could not be resolved.  If the line ended in 0x0D 0x0A, it was fine.

Fix: Delete the end-of-line character, and replace it with .

This can be done (on Eclipse Luna at least ) using File-Convert Line Delimiters To....  Not terribly elegant but available.

Comment: If anyone knows of a way of getting Eclipse to be happy with either type of line ending, that would be an even better solution.